# Micropython/Circuitpython --> Writing directly to an FTP server?

Tags: camera, ftp, esp32, micropython

Is it possible to write to a file directly on an FTP server without first writing the file locally? In other words: writing to a remote file from local memory.

```
Board: ESP32-CAM
IDE: Thonny
Language: MicroPython (Lemariva's firmware)
```

```
    from ftplib import FTP
    import camera

    ftp = FTP('192.168.1.65', '2121')
    ftp.login('user', '12345')
    ftp.cwd("/Cam/")

    filename = "test.jpeg"

    camera.init(0, format=camera.JPEG, fb_location=camera.PSRAM)
    camera.quality(10)
    camera.framesize(camera.FRAME_240X240)

    pic = camera.capture()
    fh = open(filename, 'rwb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+filename, fh)
    fh.close()
```

I'm assuming that I have to convert the **camera.capture()** object into a Byte array? But how do I do so without first capturing the image and thus writing to disk?

Comment: How to upload in-memory data/file-like object to FTP is well known problem. So maybe your should rather ask how to use your image-capturing library to provide the capture data in an in-memory buffer/file-like object.

Comment: In your example code you don't tell `camera` object what `filename` is, and you don't do anything with `pic`, so how does the captured image get into `test.jpeg`? I think you need to find out more about how to use `camera` and whether you can get the captured image from it as in-memory data.